# How can I prove that $a_n>0$ infinitely often?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, factorial, pi, fractional-part

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $$a_n:=sin(2\pi^2(2n+1)!)$$

How can I prove that $a_n>0$ infinitely often?

Clearly,   $a_n>0$ infinitely often is **equivalent** to {$\pi(2n+1)!$}$\leq 0.5$ infinitely often where {.} is fractional part function. Since $\pi$ is irrational, {$\pi(2n+1)!$} will never be zero. How can we show that {$\pi(2n+1)!$}$\leq 0.5$ infinitely many times? Graph of $y=a_n$ is available [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sl2ckn5ryv) (Desmos). On observing the graph, it **seems** that $a_n>0$ is true infinitely often. I  tried method of induction etc.  but I am not able to prove this. What are the various ways to prove it and how can it be proved?

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on previous answers and comments, you need to prove that there are infinitely many pairs $(k,n)$ such that
$$
\left|(2n+1)! - \frac{k}{\pi}\right| < \frac{1}{4\pi}.
$$
Phrased in the language of [Diophantine approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation), one needs to find infinitely many rational approximations to $\frac{1}{\pi}$ of the form $\frac{(2n+1)!}{k}$; i.e., infinitely many pairs $(k,n)$ such that
$$
\left|\frac{(2n+1)!}{k} - \frac{1}{\pi}\right| < \frac{1}{4\pi k}.
$$
It is highly nontrivial to claim that an infinity of these pairs exists. Even to say that there are infinitely many rationals $\frac{n}{k}$ such that
$$
\left|\frac{n}{k} - \frac{1}{\pi}\right| < \frac{1}{4\pi k}.
$$
requires a nontrivial application [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem). For this to still hold when $n$ is restricted to the odd factorials, one needs to show that the factorials don't "conspire" in some way so as to produce poor rational approximations to $\frac{1}{\pi}$. It certainly seems like this shouldn't happen, but actually giving a rigorous proof (in either direction) is nontrivial.

Terry Tao has a [good article](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/the-prime-number-theorem-in-arithmetic-progressions-and-dueling-conspiracies/) on "conspiracies" among prime numbers. In general, proving that conspiracies don't exist in the integers is a very difficult task.